# Proving a function of asymptotic Notation

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, functional-programming

I need help with this question. If it’s possible to do this without limits, please show. Thanks.

Q: If f(n) is Ω(n) and g(n) is O(n), then prove or disprove the following statement: f(n) is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(n) = n^2$. Clearly, we have $f(n) \in \Omega(n)$ but $f(n) \notin O(n)$. It does not require the information given for $g(n)$.

Had the quotation been to prove/disprove $f(n) \in O(g(n))$, we could proceed as follows:

Take $f(n) = n^2$ as before, along with $g(n) = \log n$. This satisfies the required criteria that $f(n) \in \Omega(n)$ and $g(n) \in O(n)$. Now clearly, $n^2 > \log n ~~ \forall n \ge 2$. Thus, we have a case where $f(n) \notin O(g(n))$.